# How do I incorporate Math.random based off of the percentage of a value?

Tags: javascript, game-development

I want to add a random modifier to this code, something that will either add to or subtract from the damage based off of a range of +-20% of the base value.  The damage would randomize between a range of 80% of result to 120% of result.  For a numeric example:

attacker.Strength(20) - defender.Defense(10) = result

20 - 10 = range(8 to 12)

```
var Fight = function (attacker, defender) {
    var result;
    result = (attacker.Strength - defender.Defense);
    defender.HP = defender.HP - result;

    if(defender.HP >= 1) {
         return defender.Name + " has taken " + result + " damage!";
    } else {
         return defender.Name + " has been slain";
    }
};
```

Comment: You should lowercase your function and property names, as they are no constructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between zero and one. Map this to your range from `0.8` to `1.2` with this:

```
var factor = Math.random() * 0.4 + 0.8;
//                |           |     |
//              [0, 1[        |     |
//                    \      /      |
//                    [0, 0.4[     /
//                         \      /
//                        [0.8, 1,2[
var result = Math.round((attacker.Strength - defender.Defense) * factor);
```

Not sure whether you want to round somewhere so that your player's health points are always natural numbers. If not, you should change your death condition to `defender.HP > 0`.

Comment: Math.random may return any value between 0 and 1 e.g. 0.45.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  I was over thinking the equation considerably.

Answer (score 1):

As in `Math.random() * 0.4`?

```
result = (attacker.Strength - defender.Defense) * (0.8 + Math.random() * 0.4);
```

Answer (score 0):

For eaxact +/- 20%, use `random` to generate two numbers only i.e. `0, 1`.

If `0`, treat it as `+` and if `1`, treat it as `-` e.g. below:

```
   var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random()); //it will return 0 or 1
   if(randomNum ==0){
      //write +20% code here
      result = (attacker.Strength - defender.Defense)*1.2;
   }else{
      //write -20% code here
      result = (attacker.Strength - defender.Defense)*0.8;
   }
```

EDIT: For range based, its much simpler.

```
  var factor = 0.8 + Math.random()*0.4;
  result = (attacker.Strength - defender.Defense)*factor ;
```

Comment: How can you use `random` to generate only one of two numbers?

Comment: @Bergi Please check the logic I mentioned. First it will generate decimal values between 0 and 1. Then `round` will round it to either 0 or 1.

Comment: Ah, there was no code when I wrote this. Still, the OP wants a factor in "*between a range of 80% of result to 120%*" and not one or the other

Comment: My answer was to return either 80% or 120%. For range base, I will edit the answer.